# url.contains, url.startsWith, Other examples?

Tags: java, android

Well it is hard to explain, 
I searched the internet for the answer, unfortunately I can't find any, maybe because I don't know what is it called though.

It's like
url.CONTAINS
url.STARTSWITH

What's the capitalized thing called? Class? Object? 
Plus, if it's possible if I can get a list of things to put after url."Class/Object/Whatever it is called".

Comment: its called a method. If you look at the Url class documentation, it's split between fields, constructors and methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url` is an instance of a class, and `contains` and `startsWith` are public variables as they do not have parentheses after them. However, I think you may have accidentally ommitted those, in which case `contains()` becomes a member function (aka method aka function) of the `url` class.

Both of the example methods you gave are part of the [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) class. An example usage would be:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com"; //create an object of the String class with the name url
if(url.startsWith("http")) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "This URL uses the http protocol");
}
```

I have provided Android sample code and links as you tagged the question Android.

Comment: url is an instance of the String class, which I have linked you to. You can find the other functions of the String class in that link.

Comment: Oh wait, I edited my comment since you edited your answer which gives the answer to my another wish to know the answer. Thanks for the help! It helps me alot. :)